# Azure AD - Cannot set Application Registration Key Credential with Type "Sign"

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to set a custom signing key for an Azure AD Application Registration. However, I get a confusing error message and cannot complete the request.

I tried to set the credential using multiple strategies:

- PowerShell New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential command
- Microsoft Graph API
- Manipulating the Application Registrations Manifest directly in Azure Portal

Microsoft Graph returns a simple "Bad Request", whereas PowerShell and Azure Portal are more specific in their responses:

`"The value for the property "usage" in one of your credentials is invalid. Acceptable values are Sign, Verify."`

The interesting thing about this error is that I am specifying the usage as "Sign".

PowerShell code snippet:

```
$appObjectID = $appRegistration.ObjectId
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cer.Import("<path-to-certificate>")
$bin = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)
$bin = $cer.GetCertHash()
$base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)

New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential `
    -ObjectId $appObjectID `
    -CustomKeyIdentifier $base64Thumbprint `
    -Type AsymmetricX509Cert `
    -Usage Sign `
    -Value $base64Value `
    -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() `
    -EndDate $cer.NotAfter.ToString()
```

Error message:

```
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: The value for the property "usage" in one of your credentials is invalid. Acceptable values are Sign, Verify.
RequestId: <id>
DateTimeStamp: <timestamp>
Details: PropertyName  - keyCredentials.keyId, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidKeyUsage
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed`
```

This is based on the documentation: [MS Docs: New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0). However, I think there is a mistake in this documentation, since they use a randomly generated GUID as input for the parameter ObjectID, which should be the ObjectID of the Application Registration I want to add the new key credential to. So I replaced this keyId with the ObjectId of my Application Registration. (If I directly use the code from MS Docs, I get a "Request_ResourceNotFound" error because the command can't find the Application Registration with this random GUID in Azure AD.)

Things I have tried:

- Change `-Usage Sign` to `-Usage "Sign"`
- Adding a "Verify" credential to the App (works as expected) with this command

When I try to directly modify the Manifest in Azure Portal, I basically get the same error message:
`Failed to update <app-name> application. Error detail: The value for the property "usage" in one of your credentials is invalid. Acceptable values are Sign, Verify.`
[Screenshot from error in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjZbN.png)

Is there maybe a issue that some parameters cannot be used this way when setting a "Sign" credential?

Thanks in advance for any help and regards!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/using-powershell-to-configure-a-signing-certificate-for-a-saml-based-sso-enterprise-application/#:~:text=note%3A%20the%20passwordcredentials%20is%20required%20in%20the%20above%20request.)? Sounds like it wants credentials for the PFX file. Do you need to set that with [New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) first?

Comment: Thanks for this hint! I haven't seen this one before.

The solution in the linked article worked for me! I could set the Key Credentials and the correspondign Password Credential using Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ash (see his comment to my initial question) I found the solution in [this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/using-powershell-to-configure-a-signing-certificate-for-a-saml-based-sso-enterprise-application/#:%7E:text=note%3A%20the%20passwordcredentials%20is%20required%20in%20the%20above%20request.) article. I followed the tutorial and could set the "Sign" Key Credential using Graph API after also including a "Verify" Key Credential and a corresponding Password Credential into the request body.